# The POST method is not supported for this route in Laravel when external api sends data to me

Tags: laravel, api, http, post, get

I'm submitting these parameters to an external API at [www.sample.com/gateway](http://www.sample.com/gateway)

```
<form action="www.sample.com/gateway/" method="POST">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantCode" value="123abc">
                    <input type="hidden" name="MerchantRefNo" value="1234">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Particualrs" value="Transaction_type=Bill;Account Number=4321;Account Name=John Doe;Email Address=jd@test.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Amount" value="100">
                    <input type="hidden" name="PayorName" value="John Doe">
                    <input type="hidden" name="PayorEmail" value="jd@test.com">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURLOK" value="success.php">
                    <input type="hidden" name="ReturnURLError" value="{{ url('/paymentdetails') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="Hash" value="{{  md5('123abc' . '1234' . 100">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn  btn-primary " value="POST TO GATEWAY"><i class="far fa-credit-card"></i> PAY NOW </button>
                  </form>
```

After which, on the `ReturnURLError`

Controller

```
public function getPaymentDetail()
    {
        
        $response = Http::get('https://sample.com/api.php');
        return $response->json();
    }
```

Route

```
Route::get('/paymentdetails', 'App\Http\Controllers\PaymentController@getPaymentDetail');
```

I am getting `The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.` when external api sends back data to me.

I triend changing the route to post but then the error becomes `The GET method is not supported in this route`

Can someone help?

Comment: can you explain the flow? and do you have experience with GET vs POST requests in general?

Comment: Hello, I edited my post. Kindly check.

Comment: You don't have a POST route defined. Define one.

Comment: change `Route::get` to `Route::post`. the external api is making a POST request on /paymentdetails and not a GET request

Comment: The problem is, when i change to ```Route::get``` the error says ```the POST method is not supported for this route. ``` and when i change it to ```Route::post``` the error says ```the GET method is not supported for this route```. This is weird lol

Comment: i'm a little concerned you're dealing with payment information but not understanding the difference between HTTP GET and POST methods. If its something within your control, maybe look at laravel's cashier packages. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/billing for stripe and paddle (if you use those payment services)